# Is there any way to allow user to search for images on my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, web, gallery

My client asked me to allow user to search for images on the website using the search bar in Wordpress. It is a big client so really don't want to lose this job. Please help me already spent many days looking for that.

Basically he wants the images to popup when somebody input the keywords. Very simple example:

1. user digit "cat" on the search bar
2. cat images are shown in a sort of
   tiled-gallery

I've been struggling for days to reach that,
thanks!!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  and please describe what you have tried and rejected so far so potential answerers don't waste their time.

Comment: Just googling https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+image+search there appear to be lots of possibilities,plugins, ways to tag images etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few image search WordPress plugins available?

**I list out below:**

1. Relevanssi – A better search
2. Search Everything
3. SearchWP
4. Ajax Search Pro
5. Google Custom Search